# Copy raw data into specific cells of a target sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets within the same workbook, namely sheet1 ("rawdata") and sheet2 ("Overview).

I copy downloaded data into sheet1 ("rawdata"). Here the number of rows vary but heading/columns are always the same. After this I need to copy specific cells into another worksheet.

Here are the "rules" I was thinking about:

1) Always copy cells from the rawdata sheet E9, W9, X9 and Y9 into a specific cell in the target sheet. I had something like this (which worked):

```
Worksheets("overview").Range("X10").Value = Worksheets("rawdata").Range("E9").Value
```

2) Always copy the value within column E in the lastrow. However, the last row is varying from rawdata to rawdata while the column (E) stays the same. I tried something like this: (not working)

```
....= Worksheets("rawdata").Range("E1").End(xlDown).Value
```

3) The script should be linked to the button, when I click the button again to insert the data from the sheet rawdata, the data should be inserted in the next (following) column of worksheet overview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: The most reliable way to find the last cell in a range can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Answer (score 2):

Assumes column E always has data. Which in this case should be true.

Sorry tried to simplify and broke it.

```
LastRow_WithDataInColumnE = Worksheets("rawdata").Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Should be

```
With Worksheets("rawdata")
    LastRow_WithDataInColumnE = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Now .Rows.Count should refer to Worksheets("rawdata")

```
Worksheets("overview").Range("X10").Value = Worksheets("rawdata").Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row.Value
```

Should be

```
With Worksheets("rawdata")
    Worksheets("overview").Range("X10").Value = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row.Value
End With
```

There is a discussion here [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920). Suggests a better solution for situations where there is no data in Column E or where rows have been deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed there is always data in columnE, however, the code is not working. In the "Rows.Count" the mistake has been detected with the message (invalid reference). :-( do you have ad hoc an idea why this message has been shown?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get the last data range in column E:

```
Public Function FindLastColumnECellAvailable()
    FindLastColumnECellAvailable = "E" & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E:E"))
End Function
```

Then you will have this:

[image]

At the end just read the cell value:

```
Range(FindLastColumnECellAvailable).Value
```

[image]

Greetings

**Sorry**
An apologize "in advance", I just read the date,  hope this will help you yet or anyone else, it's my second day